# Why can't I import bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs

I have installed bootstrap in the project root but it returns error "Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.css'. I have been getting errors left and right in react but I am choosing to focus on this one first.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Main from './Main.jsx';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Main />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: What do you mean by “installed at the project root”?

Answer (score 0):

> First install the package from npm.
>
> Then, copy this **import
> "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";**
>
> And paste it in **index.js** file

Hope this might help